# Remove characters before and after a special character VBA

Tags: vba

I have a set of data with strings such as, 1782_eqjobs.hostname, 519_fid_quant.hostname.

I want to be able to keep all of the characters within the first '_' and '.', then remove the rest.

For example;

1782_eqjobs.hostname -> eqjobs

519_fid_quant.hostname -> fid_quant

Is it possible to use a macro to preform this?

Comment: See [How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops).

Comment: yes vba will do it.  So will a formula.  There are many ways that this can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple formula will do it:

```
=MID(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1),FIND("_",A1)+1,LEN(A1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex pattern of

```
_(.*)\.
```

and then extract group 1 of match. This is a little fragile as is based on all strings being in the layout your provided without multiple instances of `_ some text .`

[Try it](https://regex101.com/r/1htHKm/2)

I mean an implementation such as:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()

    Debug.Print GetString("1782_eqjobs.hostname")

End Sub

Public Function GetString(ByVal inputString As String) As Variant
    Dim matches As Object

    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "_(.*)\."
        If .test(inputString) Then
            Set matches = .Execute(inputString)
            GetString = matches(0).SubMatches(0)
            Exit Function
        End If
    End With
    GetString = CVErr(xlErrNA)
End Function
```

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm completely new to using VBA would you be able to explain what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe..

```
Sub CleanUp()
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each c In Selection
        c.Value = Mid(c.Value, InStr(1, c.Value, "_") + 1, InStr(1, c.Value, ".") - InStr(1, c.Value, "_") - 1)
    Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a worksheet function, either in the worksheet or in VBA.

Let's assume your strings are in Range A1.

The function in the cell would look like this:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("_",A1,1)+1,(FIND(".",A1,1)-FIND("_",A1,1))-1)
```

To use it in VBA you'd put:

```
worksheetfunction.MID(A1,FIND("_",A1,1)+1,(FIND(".",A1,1)-FIND("_",A1,1))-1)
```

Hope that helps!

Phil

Comment: `worksheetfunction.MID(A1,FIND("_",A1,1)+1,(FIND(".",A1,1)-FIND("_",A1,1))-1)` will not work.  First `Mid` is a natural vba function.  Second all the `Find` would need the `worksheetfunction.` each.  But why not use `INSTR` instead?  But then you would have @mrkrister's answer.

Comment: I have since learnt much, and I agree that my previous answer was terrible. I must apologize all. Thank you @ScottCraner for correcting me.